# reactjs open file in new tab with a tag and url from backend using.map()

Tags: reactjs

I'm seeing an issue where I can only open the file if I use import, and it cannot open direct from the location. It works on a regular html file, but not react jsx. I also had another project with react where this was working fine and never an issue.

full code repo: https://codesandbox.io/s/open-file-kb2q6

data file:

***Note:*** I've tried the following combinations...

- `docs/file1.pdf`
- `./docs/file1.pdf`
- `../docs/file1.pdf`

```
const files = [
  {
    name: "file1",
    url: "./docs/file1.pdf"
  },
  {
    name: "file2",
    url: "./docs/file2.pdf"
  },
  {
    name: "file3",
    url: "./docs/file3.pdf"
  },
  {
    name: "file4",
    url: "./docs/file4.pdf"
  }
];

export { files };
```

react's app.js file:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { files } from "./data/GetLinksFromBackend.js";

import testFile from "./docs/file1.pdf";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {files.map((file, i) => (
        <a key={i} href={file.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          {file.name}
          <br />
          <br />
        </a>
      ))}
      <a href={testFile} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Test File</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

reproduce issue: https://kb2q6.csb.app/

- notice file1 - file4 does not work and opens up blank tabs.
- notice Test File works and opens up the file in a preview in a new tab.

Anyone have any idea to fix file1-file4?

Comment: I think you're confusing JS import paths for relative URL paths.

Comment: Are the files in `/docs` actually being served? It seems like the only reason the test file can be opened/previewed is because it's contained in your (React) app's bundle (because of your `import` statement), while the other files are not being served

Comment: @BrianThompson not sure, I can pull up the same code from another project(private) where it is working just fine. It's so weird...

Comment: In the browser, an `href` pointing to `./data/file.pdf` is instructing the browser to look for it at `domain.com/data/file/pdf`. It has no way of knowing that you mean to go into the folder inside of `src`. Where as within the JS, a relative path for an import will look relative to your current directory.

Comment: Try moving your docs folder inside the `public` folder of your React app and see if they then become accessible.

Comment: the (working project) is using the current `<a href="docs/file1.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">file 1</a>`, but when I try that it doesn't work...

Comment: @nbokmans actually I remember having to do that. I think that might be it. Thanks :D... yup, that was it

Comment: @nbokmans the reason being, `public` is typically what is served to the web and would then make the URL `domain.com/docs` match the real folder structure `public/docs`.

Comment: How about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61410909/dynamically-loading-json-files-with-fetch-after-component-mounts-in-react/61411455#61411455 answer ? I know is not exactly what you are asking, but it can be useful.